# How to display AM or PM input type TIME

Tags: angular, typescript, datetime

I'am using input type time and when I submit form it become format 20 hours. How to convert to 12 hours and display AM PM. I try using like this code bellow but I got this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined`.

HTML

```
<input class="form-control" type="time" format-value="hh:mm tt" min="01:00" max="12:00" formControlName="time" ngModel >
```

Component

```
onSave() {
      var timeSplit = this.registerConfigForm.value.end.split(':'),
      hours,
      minutes,
      meridian;
      hours = timeSplit[0];
      minutes = timeSplit[1];
      if (hours > 12) {
        meridian = 'PM';
        hours -= 12;
      } else if (hours < 12) {
        meridian = 'AM';
        if (hours == 0) {
          hours = 12;
        }
      } else {
        meridian = 'PM';
      }
      alert(hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + meridian);
    }
```

Comment: `this.registerConfigForm.value.time` right? instead of `.end`?

Comment: Have a look at the Date Pipe (short):  https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: Or here for HTML input type: date-time... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti.. yup true...sorry my bad...